# Set column to some value if nested query returns null

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL query

```
SELECT s.id,
       s.First_Name +' '+s.Last_Name AS Name,
       d1.Department_Name,
       s.Manager_Id,
       s.EmailId
FROM Fin_UserMaster s
INNER JOIN Fin_Department_Master AS d1 ON d1.id = s.Department_Id
WHERE s.id =
    (SELECT Manager_Id
     FROM Fin_UserMaster
     WHERE id= '13')
```

Now if my nested query returns null I want to give another Id in place of nested query.

For example, if nested query returns null then `s.id = '13'`, something like that.

Tried a few things, but they didn't work out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(select COALESCE(Manager_Id, 13) from Fin_UserMaster where id= '13')
```

OR

```
(select ISNULL(Manager_Id, 13) from Fin_UserMaster where id= '13')
```

EDIT: Over a large number of rows, `ISNULL` seems to be faster. However, it isn't part of SQL standard - as some of the answers on ISNULL vs COALESCE suggest.